# maven-jaxb2-plugin ignoring configuration

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using maven 3.3.9 and the maven-jaxb2-plugin 0.13.1. But when I try to generate the Java classes, the plugin is not finding my XSD-file.

My pom looks like this:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas</schemaDirectory>                                
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Everytime I'm executing the goal, I get this message:

[WARNING] No schemas to compile. Skipping XJC execution.

The directory exists under the resources folder, and the XSD is placed there. I have no other pom-files in play.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else will hit this. I had a similar issue: the configuration was not picked up by the plugin. I made it work by moving `configuration` section under `plugin` declaration instead of `execution`.

Here's how the working configuration looked like for me (I removed the upper-level elements since they do not matter):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.15.1</version>
  <configuration>                          
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/custom-schemas</schemaDirectory>                                
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  /executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Author of [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) here.

Somehow I have a feeling that you're omitting important details. This does not not add up. This is a very basic [configuration setting](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/6737f6bd504354f3a2329f6a234f9dc0b662e45e/plugin-core/src/main/java/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/AbstractXJC2Mojo.java#L166-L167), I'm curious how it can't work.

You only post the `pluginManagement` part of your `pom.xml`. If you have just this, it should not work at all as it is just and only a *declaration* of configuration, not actual usage of the plugin. You need `plugins/plugin` to actually apply the plugin:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>...</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

To analyze the problem, run `mvn -X clean generate-sources` or `mvn -X clean install` and check the applied configuration (it will be logged). Post the log here.

If this does not help, send me a PR of a minimal reproducing project under `https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support/s/schemaDirectory`, I'll take a look.